# Android Camera api not stopping preview

Tags: android, camera, preview

My problem is this:
Camera preview won't stop after taking pictures, it remains in preview mode. This happens only on Samsung S3 with android 4.4. On other devices it works.

Can you help me?

Here is my code:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    private CameraPreview mCameraPreview;
    private boolean pozeaza=false;
    View rootView;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }
    LinearLayout preview;
    boolean isPreviewRunning;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dvcamera_retake,
                container, false);

      //  mCamera = getCameraInstance();

     //   initializeCamera(mCamera);



        //mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this.getActivity(), mCamera);
        final TextView mTextField = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         preview = (LinearLayout) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        bt1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        bt2 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        bt3 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        bt4 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button4);
        bt3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        bt4.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    //  if (preview != null) {
    //      preview.addView(mCameraPreview);
    //  }
        Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!pozeaza)
                {
                    pozeaza=true;

                    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);

                }
            }
        });
        Button button1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Activity ac = (Activity) ct;

                ac.finish();

                Intent intent = new Intent(ac, MainActivity1.class);


                intent.putExtra("key", key);
                intent.putExtra("cardID", cardID);
                ac.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        bt3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                /*Activity ac = (Activity) ct;

                ac.finish();

                Intent intent = new Intent(ac, DVCameraActivitySnapSite.class);
                ac.startActivity(intent);*/
                bt3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                bt4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                bt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                bt2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            }
        });
        bt4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                progressTask().execute("");
                Activity ac = (Activity) ct;

                ac.finish();

                Intent intent = new Intent(ac, MainActivity1.class);
                intent.putExtra("result", 2);
                ac.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    //  int msec = (Integer.parseInt(config.getSnapDelay()))*1000;

        return rootView;
    }

    private Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera camera = null;
        int cameraCount = 0;

        try {
            Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
            cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
            if(camO==1)
                for ( int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++ ) {
                    Camera.getCameraInfo( camIdx, cameraInfo );
                    if ( cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT  ) {
                        try {
                            camera = Camera.open( camIdx );
                        } catch (RuntimeException e) {

                        }
                    }
                }
            else
                for ( int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++ ) {
                    Camera.getCameraInfo( camIdx, cameraInfo );
                    if ( cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK  ) {
                        try {
                            camera = Camera.open( camIdx );
                        } catch (RuntimeException e) {

                        }
                    }
                }
            //camera = Camera.open();
            //  camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            //Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

            //parameters.set("jpeg-quality", 70);
            //  parameters.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);


            //  parameters.setPictureSize(480, 640);





            //  camera.setParameters(parameters);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // cannot get camera or does not exist
        }
        return camera;
    }
    protected void initializeCamera(Camera mCamera) {
        isPreviewRunning=true;
        mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this.getActivity(), mCamera);
        preview = (LinearLayout) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        if (preview != null) {
            preview.addView(mCameraPreview);
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();  // Always call the superclass method first

        // Release the Camera because we don't need it when paused
        // and other activities might need to use it.


        if(mCamera!=null){
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            mCameraPreview.getHolder().removeCallback(mCameraPreview);
            preview.removeView(mCameraPreview);
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first

        // Get the Camera instance as the activity achieves full user focus
       /* if (mCamera == null) {
            mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this.getActivity(), mCamera);
            preview = (LinearLayout) rootView
                    .findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);

            if (preview != null) {
                preview.addView(mCameraPreview);
            }

            // initializeCamera(); // Local method to handle camera init
        }*/
    //    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);

        //if (mCamera==null){
            mCamera=getCameraInstance();
        //}
        initializeCamera(mCamera);
    }


    PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            pozeaza=false;
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH_mm_ss");
            String yourText = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            File store = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
             dateTaken=yourText;
            filename1=comp +"_" +yourText+".jpg";
            path = store.getAbsolutePath()
                    + "/com.wyseos.virtualclock/" + comp +"_" +yourText+".jpg";
            pictureFile = new File(path);




            try {
                dataBit=data;

                // BitmapFactory.Options options = new
                // BitmapFactory.Options();
                // options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                // Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
                // timestampItAndSave(bitmap);
                // camera.release();


                bt1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //bt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                bt3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                bt4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //progressTask().execute("");
                //Activity ac = (Activity) ct;

                //ac.finish();

                //Intent intent = new Intent(ac, MainActivity1.class);

                //ac.startActivity(intent);
                rotation=getRotation(getActivity());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    };


}
```